# Chrome Extension with access to online shop checkout

Tags: woocommerce, google-chrome-extension, shopify

I would like to develop a chrome extension for a charity purpose, where people can install the extension and are able to add an additional fee, depending on their cart, to the checkout.

There are other extensions which work like that, but I wonder how this works for different shops like woocommerce, shopify, Shopware, Squarespace, Wix, ...

Does anyone have a high level explanation and help me to get started?

Answer (score 1):

For Shopify your path is not using a Chrome Extension, but instead, embracing the Shopify platform itself and using Storefront API as one example. I cannot speak for anything else out there, but I can say, you're barking up the wrong tree if you want to explore using Chrome as an Extension into Shopify. Wrong tool for the job.